# MySQL update column based on another column data manipulation

Tags: mysql

I have a table looks like below:

```
id  name  value    newColumn
============================
1   Joe     22     null
2   Derk    30     null
```

**newColumn** is a newly added column and I would like to update the data for each and every rows with a specific format: concat **value** and a specific string **-CIF**

End result should be something like below:

```
id  name  value    newColumn
============================
1   Joe     22     22-CIF
2   Derk    30     30-CIF
```

May I know how to construct such update query in mySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly basic `update`:

```
update table t
    set newColumn = concat(value, '-CIF');
```

Comment: Well, I gave you almost a "code snippet is not enough" comment and a vtd :-)