# mysql update column based on another updated column

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Note, this question is not same to the [MySQL update column based on another column data manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28977222/6521116)

table order

```
| order_number | payment_amount | refund_amount | refund_status |
| 12           |  100           | 50            | 1             |
```

refund_status:

```
0: none refunded;
1: part refunded;
2: all refunded;
```

```
update order set refund_amount = refund_amount + 50, refund_status = CASE WHEN payment_amount = refund_amount + 50 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END where order_number = 12;
// refund_amount -> 100, refund_status ->1
```

Cannot get the right result (refund_amount -> 100, refund_status ->2).

But

```
update order set refund_amount = refund_amount + 50, refund_status = CASE WHEN payment_amount = refund_amount THEN 2 ELSE 1 END where order_number = 12;
// refund_amount -> 100, refund_status ->2
```

Can get the right result.

It seems update refund_status besed on the updated `refund_amount`, is it reliable?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question by showing us input and output data?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry I've made some mistake in the post. I've edited it. Check it now.

Comment: Logically then refund_amount is set before the test for refund_status - was that your real question?

Comment: As the two column update in one sql. So they should both based on the old value refund_amount, which is 50.

Comment: 'So they should both based on the old value ' - do you have a reference to support this?

Comment: No, I don't have any reference to this. that's where I can't understand.

Comment: There is an example of the exhibited behaviour in the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html see para starting 'The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the current (updated) col1 value, and the previous few paras.

Comment: @P.Salmon Got it, Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

use bracket every you use function case for system readable on your logic code.

```
update order
set refund_amount = (refund_amount + 50),
refund_status = (CASE WHEN payment_amount = refund_amount + 50 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END)
where order_number = 12;
```